# How to detect location changes with startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

I use the post iOS4 method startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges method, according to the apple documentation:

```
For applications that do not need a regular stream of location events, consider using the startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges method to start the delivery of events instead. This method is more appropriate for the majority of applications that just need an initial user location fix and need updates only when the user moves a significant distance. This interface delivers new events only when it detects changes to the device’s associated cell towers, resulting in less frequent updates and significantly lower power usage.
```

So this interface delivers new events only when it detects location changes, what method exactly can i use to detect that the location has been significantly changed, so far, i go like this:

```
if ([CLLocationManager significantLocationChangeMonitoringAvailable]) {

        [locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];

    }
```

What explicit method should i use to explicitly detect that the location has been changed significantly. Thanx.

Answer (score 1):

I do it like this:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {


// Override point for customizatio-n after application launch.
id locationValue = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey];
if (locationValue)
{
    // create a new manager and start checking for sig changes
    [self log:@"didFinishLaunchingWithOptions location key"];
    m_locManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [self log:@"didFinishLaunchingWithOptions created manager"];
    m_locManager.delegate = self;
    [self log:@"didFinishLaunchingWithOptions set delegate"];
    [m_locManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
    [self log:@"didFinishLaunchingWithOptions monitoring sig changes"];
    return YES;
}

[self log:@"didFinishLaunchingWithOptions"];    
return YES;
}

 - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
       fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
```

Comment: Please dont pay any attention to the self log: you could replace it with NSLOG

Comment: Ok, so we are ok that `[m_locManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];` will look for Significant changes, but how can i know if a change Has Benn detected by this method?

Comment: I guess that:  - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
       fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation does this.

Comment: I didn't used any of your code above, also, `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:`is deprecated in iOS6.